# Unable to Get the Proper Result : SQL Query Help Needed

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

Dear All,

```
rs3=st.executeQuery("select * from "+sdata[j]+" where Username='"+idata[i]+"'");
        while(rs3.next())
        {

                %><td><%out.println(rs3.getString("Final_Grade"));%></td><%


        }
```

In the above JSP Code,sdata[j] is the array of table names and idata[i] is the array of usernames. what i am trying to achieve is, to retrieve final_grade from the tables sdata[j] with the username==idata[i] . Since the username is existing in some table it displays the final grade, but when no record found in the table i want print it as "Null" instead of Final_Grade . Is this possible to implement?

Comment: the standard way to do this would be to inspect the number of records returned and/or the value of Final_Grade retrieved from the query; if there are no records, or if the returned value is NULL, print "NULL"; otherwise, print its value

Comment: Since there is no student record in the table , it will not print Null. Is there any Query to print Null values if there is no record exist

Comment: I noticed that after posting my comment; I edited my comment to reflect that case

Comment: Thank you for helping me.Is there any query Available to solve this

Comment: re: "Is there any Query to print Null values if there is no record exist", querying is separate from handling what is returned by the query;  any query might return zero, 1, or many rows;  what you do with those results is separate from the query itself

Comment: add a check for the size of `rs3` before looping through it with `rs3.next()`;  if the size is 0, no rows were returned

Comment: out.println(rs3.next()); is displaying true or false only

Comment: how do you intend to find out if there are no records int the table?  you do that by issuing a query;  the query will return a result set with 0 or more records;  so no: the only way to do this is to issue the query and then branch based on the results of that query

Comment: how about .rowCount() ?

Comment: ... or you can set a flag inside of the .next() loop, and after the loop test to see if that flag was set; if it wasn't, there were no rows for .next() to loop over, in which case you print the "NULL";  or, this fancy trick might help you : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/RetrievearowcountfromaResultSet.htm

Comment: rs3=st.executeQuery("select * from "+sdata[j]+" where Username='"+idata[i]+"'");
   //out.println(rs3.toString());
   if(rs3.next())
   {
     %><td><%out.println(rs3.getString("Final_Grade"));%></td><%
      }
   else
   {
    %><td><%out.println("null");%></td><%
   }

Comment: Its Done @landru27. Thank you for your time

Comment: the `if(rs3.next()) { ... } else { ... }` construct will function, but will fail to print all of the rows if there are multiple results for a given query;  that *might* be suitable here, but it's important to be skeptical even about your own data;  for example, you would want to know if a student ever had more than one Final_Grade in the database, and your approach here will hide that fact;  see my answer for a construct that will *both* show multiple rows in the result *and* print "NULL" for zero rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer based on my most recent comment:

```
rs3=st.executeQuery("select * from "+sdata[j]+" where Username='"+idata[i]+"'");

    flagRows = false;
    while(rs3.next())
    {
    %><td><%out.println(rs3.getString("Final_Grade"));%></td><%
    flagRows = true;
    }

    if (flagRows == false)
    {
    %><td><%out.println("NULL");%></td><%
    }
```